# Turning an array into an array of hashes using .each

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, each

Given this array of String names, return an array of Hashes. Each Hash should have the keys name and id, which will represent their unique identifier in the form of an integer. The ids can start at 1 and then go up by one.

output should look like:

```
[{:name=>"Bruno", :id=>1},
 {:name=>"Bella", :id=>2},
 {:name=>"Ringo", :id=>3},
 {:name=>"Spot", :id=>4},
 {:name=>"Fluffy", :id=>5},
 {:name=>"Snowball", :id=>6},
 {:name=>"Doc", :id=>7}]
```

I'm trying to do something like this but I'm having trouble coming up with the right syntax and methods.

```
NAMES = ['Bella', 'Bruno', 'Ringo', 'Spot', 'Fluffy', 'Snowball', 'Doc']

def array_to_hash_array(names)
  
  i = 1
  NAMES.each do |name|
    
    name = Hash.new(:name => name, :id => i)
    
    NAMES << name
    i += 1
  end
  
  return NAMES
end  

puts array_to_hash_array(NAMES)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) and [with_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index) to return an array of Hash objects with the *name* and *id* values:

```rb
names = ['Bella', 'Bruno', 'Ringo', 'Spot', 'Fluffy', 'Snowball', 'Doc']

def array_to_hash_array(array)
  array.map.with_index(1) do |name, index|
    { id: index, name: name }
  end
end

p array_to_hash_array(names)
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"Bella"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"Bruno"}, {:id=>3, :name=>"Ringo"}, {:id=>4, :name=>"Spot"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"Fluffy"}, {:id=>6, :name=>"Snowball"}, {:id=>7, :name=>"Doc"}]
```

I've reworked the code in your example to produce the correct output (with some notes on what was tweaked):

```rb
# variable renamed from NAMES as uppercase is meant for constants
names = ['Bella', 'Bruno', 'Ringo', 'Spot', 'Fluffy', 'Snowball', 'Doc']

def array_to_hash_array(array)
  # added a result array for building up the final object to be returned
  result = []
  i = 1

  # changed to iterate over the passed in array object
  array.each do |name|  
    # using Hash literal instead of Hash.new since it allows us 
    # to specify contents of hash object directly
    name = { :name => name, :id => i }
    
    # push to result object instead of same iterated array
    result << name
    i += 1
  end
  
  # return built up result object
  result
end

p array_to_hash_array(names)
# => [{:name=>"Bella", :id=>1}, {:name=>"Bruno", :id=>2}, {:name=>"Ringo", :id=>3}, {:name=>"Spot", :id=>4}, {:name=>"Fluffy", :id=>5}, {:name=>"Snowball", :id=>6}, {:name=>"Doc", :id=>7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Indexing an Array with #each_with_index

As [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html) includes the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) module, you can invoke [Array#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) to create the data structure you want using the array index of each element of your *names* array with a suitable offset. For example:

```
names = %w[Bella Bruno Ringo Spot Fluffy Snowball Doc]
array = []
names.each_with_index do |name, index|
  array << { name: name, id: index.succ }
end
```

Note the use of [Integer#succ](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-succ), which is used to offset the index by one. Since Ruby arrays are zero-indexed, you need to increment the index value passed in by #each_with_index to get the numbering the way you want.

You can pretty-print the array with [Kernel#pp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-pp) (e.g. `pp array`) to verify the results:

> ```
> [{:name=>"Bella", :id=>1},
>  {:name=>"Bruno", :id=>2},
>  {:name=>"Ringo", :id=>3},
>  {:name=>"Spot", :id=>4},
>  {:name=>"Fluffy", :id=>5},
>  {:name=>"Snowball", :id=>6},
>  {:name=>"Doc", :id=>7}]
> ```

### Note on Hash Key Ordering

As you can see, this populated the array of hashes the way you wanted, and in the specific format you're looking for. However, it's important to remember that while the order of keys in a hash are kept in insertion order in mainline Ruby, you shouldn't really rely on that behavior. Conceptually, hashes are unordered, so:

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"Bella"},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"Bruno"},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"Ringo"},
 {:id=>4, :name=>"Spot"},
 {:id=>5, :name=>"Fluffy"},
 {:id=>6, :name=>"Snowball"},
 {:id=>7, :name=>"Doc"}] ==
   [{:name=>"Bella", :id=>1},
    {:name=>"Bruno", :id=>2},
    {:name=>"Ringo", :id=>3},
    {:name=>"Spot", :id=>4},
    {:name=>"Fluffy", :id=>5},
    {:name=>"Snowball", :id=>6},
    {:name=>"Doc", :id=>7}]
#=> true
```

Comment: You can use `with_index(1)`  to start from one.

Comment: @Rajagopalan That comes from a different module, specifically Enumerator. [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) is *not* mixed into Array, and thus requires another method call. In either case, one has to handle the offset from zero, whether as a method argument or in the body of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it
`names.each_with_index.map { |x,i| {name: x, id: i+1} }`

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['Bella', 'Bruno', 'Ringo', 'Spot', 'Fluffy', 'Snowball', 'Doc']
```

```
enum = 1.step
  #=> (1.step) 
names.map { |name| { name: name, id: enum.next } }
  #=> [{:name=>"Bella", :id=>1}, {:name=>"Bruno", :id=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Ringo", :id=>3}, {:name=>"Spot", :id=>4},
  #    {:name=>"Fluffy", :id=>5}, {:name=>"Snowball", :id=>6},
  #    {:name=>"Doc", :id=>7}]
```

See [Numeric#step](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) and [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

Answer (score 0):

You could zip ([Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip)) to an endless range ([beginless-endless-range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html#class-Range-label-Beginless-2FEndless+Ranges)) then map to the desired hash:

```
ary = ['Bella', 'Bruno', 'Ringo', 'Spot', 'Fluffy', 'Snowball', 'Doc']

ary.zip(1..).map { |name, id| {name: name, id: id} }
```